# Physical laptop lock

Tags: physical

I brought this really great laptop, but I cannot find something that I can lock the laptop physically to the desk or prevent a thief from grabbing this laptop.
There is no "universal" hole there that 99% of the laptops have... not that ive noticed at... (I mean thing like that: http://www1.dealextreme.com/productimages/sku_0045_1.jpg)

What would be a good solution, for physically protecting a laptop that does not support standard laptop locks?

Comment: Hi @ShadowPress, welcome to [security.se]! Please read the [FAQ], and also [ask] - "shopping recommendations" are discouraged here. I edited your question slightly, to make it more of a generalized question, looking for a solution and not a product.

Comment: Have you read this question? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/best-practices-for-physically-securing-a-notebook

Comment: @AviD makes a great point about keeping it a generalized question, but it may help if you provide a link or description of the laptop/manufacturer.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you put it to the locked cabinet or locked drawer in your desk? Keep it simple.

Comment: These are good solutions but are of course not portable.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few existing laptop-locking devices which can be adapted to laptops which do not feature a [Kensington security slot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot); e.g. my friend Google found [this](http://www.securitysolutions.ca/main.php?p=productdisplay&pid=spyder) and [that](http://www.securitysolutions.ca/main.php?p=productdisplay&pid=Benji2). They are relatively clunky apparatus which grips around the laptop around its main hinge; I have not used any, but I believe such a system can be effective, in the following sense: a thief would have to considerably damage the laptop in order to steal it. Still, they are a bit lacking on the glamourous side of things.

Are you sure your laptop has no Kensington hole ? These are pretty standard nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

There are some "luggage safes" that will let you wrap your kit up in a metal mesh that is lockable. [Sample](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NGFVUU) (this one is aimed at a large backpack, but they also make some for smaller things). [Lockable laptop bag](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0011UJX8I).